# Caption position in a TSpeedButton

Tags: canvas, c++builder, caption, glyph

I'm using C++Builder 11 Alexandria.
Is there a way to position a SpeedButton caption always centered even if there is a glyph?
Caption can be positioned at right, at left, at top or at bottom of the glyph, but I need to position it over the glyph.
I use SpeedButton because using glyph I can distinguish pressed and unpressed state so I can't use, for example, a `TImage` and use it's `OnClick` event to simulate a button.

Also to write text in the SpeedButton would be a solution but the SpeedButton `Canvas` property is protected so I can't use `DrawText` and in the SpeedButton there is no `OnDraw` event.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you could create a new VCL component where inherit from `TCustomSpeedButton` and add a new property (`CenterCaption`). You'd then `override` `Paint()` in which you first call `::Paint();` to let it do the bulk of the painting and then you paint the value of `CenterCaption` in the center. In this component, you would not put `Caption` among the `__published:` properties, but instead `CenterCaption`. So, for the definition of the component, you could copy the definition of `TSpeedButton` and modify it slightly.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks for your suggestion. Honestly I don't know how to create a custom component but I will find some guide to do it.

Comment: Why not remove Caption completely and Add the Text to your Gyph? You can have multiple images in single Glyph to determine states of the button (down/up) ... at least in VCL

Comment: @Spectre - It is a possibility but text will change at runtime, I should change the glyph at runtime. I think that change only the text would be more practical.

Comment: @TedLyngmo - I'm trying to create my SpeedButton starting from TCustomSpeedButton. I posted a question [How to customize the Caption property of a VCL component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71396761/how-to-customize-the-caption-property-of-a-vcl-component). I don't know how to make my `CustomCaption` to behave like the original `Caption`: when I change the font nothing happens in my `CustomCaption`. The `CM_FONTCHANGED` message, if generated, does not affect my `CustomCaption`, can you give me a tip?